# How to freeze "start" button during jquery animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

A quick question about jquery animations...
I've done a rather long jquery animation (about 45 seconds) which has many layers of setTimeout and callbacks. In short, I'm in deep trouble if someone clicks "start" while the animation is running, because then it will start a new animation loop without stopping the old one, so I'll have two running at the same time... you see the problem.

Is there any technique out there which would let me either 1) block the functionality of the "start" button until the animation is finished, or 2) stop an animation loop in the middle and reinitialize if a user hits the "start" button ?

My thanks in advance - any advice would be VERY much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start your animation disable your button like

```
$('#yourbuttonid').attr("disabled", true);
```

Then on your complete off animation renable the button

```
$('#continueButton').attr("disabled", false);
```

Comment: `prop()` instead of `attr()` will be faster if the jQuery version is recent enough

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following code to your start button's click handler:

```
if($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
    return;
}
$(this).addClass('disabled');
```

Then you just need to `removeClass('disabled')` when the animation stuff finished.

Comment: If it's a real `button`, you could even use `prop('disabled', true)`. (I'm sure *you* already know that, but for the OP's sake.)

Comment: If it's a real button then that would be better - for the check you could then use a simple `if(this.disabled)`

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag at the beginning of the animation and remove it at the end. Then you'd reference that flag using the click event of the button to determine if the action should be performed or not.

```
$('.your-button').click(function( event ){
    if( flag == true )
        // do animation
    else
        event.preventDefault();
});
```